# Emoticons corrupting between server and Android app

Tags: java, php, android, emoji, emoticons

In chat app, received emoticon messages are not showing correctly.

Encoded before sending in Android:

```
     URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8")
```

**EDIT1** Getting messages in PHP:

```
  $sqlmessage = "SELECT m.id, m.fromuid, m.touid, m.sentdt, m.read, m.readdt, m.messagetext , m.timeSent, u.username from messages m \n"
. "left join users u on u.Id = m.fromuid WHERE `touid` = ".$userId." AND `read` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 "; 
.
.
.
  if ($resultmessage = $db->query($sqlmessage))         
                        {
                        while ($rowmessage = $db->fetchObject($resultmessage))
                            {
                            $out .= "<message  from='".$rowmessage->username."'  sendt='".$rowmessage->sentdt."' text='".$rowmessage->messagetext."' timeSent='".$rowmessage->timeSent."' />";
                            error_log($rowmessage->messagetext."\r\n", 3, "error.log");
                            }
                        }
.
.
.
echo $out;
```

Here, emoticons are printed from php correctly. So far it's all good.

But when trying to display received messages with emoticons, problems occur.
either they show up as garbage text or strange characters.

*Response comes as a string from sendHttpRequest, then string is parsed ..etc*

**EDIT2**

**print sent message** in log (smily face):

```
   message is ��
```

**print received message** in log (the smily face):

```
   message value from xml replyߘĀ2015-02-10 00:57:07.389
```

I tried everything I know, reviewed almost every question here about emoticons but to no avail. Last thing I tried this (in XMLHandler):

```
     URLDecoder.decode(attributes.getValue(MessageInfo.MESSAGETEXT),"UTF-8")
```

How can I recover the received message?

I need it back just like the message string was sent, so that EmojiconEditText can display emoticons properly.

**Note:**

- this only happens when the message has an emoticon
- emoticons are sent and stored correctly on server database, problem happens when trying to display received emoticons only
- EmojiconEditText is doing well rendering emoticons

Comment: So the message containing the emoticon goes from an Android device to the server OK, and is stored OK, but from the server back to another handset, it is corrupted?

Comment: @halfer no, they are fine even in the php code that retrieves them, but when XMLHandler gets the string, it's curropted

Comment: It seems you mean "yes"! The first path (handset to server) is OK, and the second path (server to handset) is not, correct? If it is corrupted when it is received on the second handset, you need to work out if the corruption occurred in Android reception or server transmission. Just because it is stored OK in the server database does not mean the server sent it on correctly.

Comment: @halfer how can i tell if it's in Android reception or server transmission?
I use the same way to receive as to send msg,what could i be missing?

Comment: Can we see the PHP code that sends the message from the server to the handset? Also, it might be worth writing some server code (e.g. a small web app) to pull the UTF-8 data from the database and display it on a web page, just to prove this works. I understand you believe it has saved to the database correctly, but you need to make sure.

Comment: @halfer, please check the edited php code.

Comment: What HTTP headers are sent from the server to the mobile device, when this XML message gets corrupted? Are you declaring the charset there? (You should, I think). Please edit in a small example of an XML reply into your question, plus all the headers that are normally set.

Comment: (Unrelated: you should not be concatenating SQL these days - that `$userId` should be a bound parameter. May not be a SQL injection vuln, but good to fix anyway.)

Comment: Assuming your mobile service pulls the reply from the server, via something like cURL, the headers would be set by PHP using `header()`. It sounds like you are not setting any at all, and so would only get the default ones from Apache. All HTTP services should use them, for example this Stack Overflow page sets eight headers, one of which is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. [There are two suitable types for XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_and_MIME), I would guess yours should be `application/xml`.

Comment: @halfer thanks for bearing with me.I added header("Content-type: application/xml; charset=\"utf8mb4_unicode_ci\""); as first stmt in php, is this the correct way?because it didn't fix it

Comment: Adding a header is correct insofar as transmission goes, but it depends what your receiving Android library will understand (and I've no idea about that, never developed for it). However the `unicode_ci` bit is almost certainly wrong - that looks like a database character set from MySQL, which won't be understood as a HTTP character set. Try `Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8` instead.

Comment: Also, you will need to find some debugging tools for Android to tell you the character set of HTTP replies. Maybe the emulator can do this (a rhetorical question, as again I don't know - you will have to research it).

Comment: @halfer, same thing.Maybe it's worth noting that only some old emoticons like ☺❤✌☝ show up just fine,could this give a clue?

Comment: It might, but I'm not the person to ask. I think you need that debugging tool `:-)`.